# Python datetime.strmp Value Error while getting time in hours minutes and seconds from CSV File

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I am trying to convert the string that contains hours, minutes and seconds to datetime from a csv file but always get error "ValueError: time data 'created_at' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'". The code is as below :

```
import csv
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime


path = r'C:\Users\Ahmed Ismail Khalid\Desktop\test\_jonasschnelli__tweets.csv'


with open(path,'rt',encoding="utf-8") as f :
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader :
   print(row[1])
   print("Converted time is :", datetime.strptime(row[1], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

The csv file is in the format :

```
id       |       created_at                  |   text
1        |       1/15/2018  6:12:16 AM       |  this is sample text
2        |       1/11/2018  6:58:27 AM       |  this is sample text
3        |       1/10/2018  9:39:33 PM       |  this is sample text
4        |       1/10/2018  8:47:35 PM       |  this is sample text
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should skip the first row of your csv file which is:

> id       |       created_at                  |   text

Also, your sample date and the format dont match.

The following block code should work if your date format is:

> Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second Locale

```
for idx, row in enumerate(ints):
    if idx != 1:
        print("Converted time is :", datetime.strptime('1/11/2018 6:30:23 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p'))
```

Also, make sure to take a look at [strptime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Thanks but refer to the updated question. Due to some problem in my connection I accidentally posted the wrong question before I could edit it.

Comment: It gives the error name ints is not defined. I even changed it to 
    print("Converted time is :", datetime.strptime(row[1], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
but still get a the valueerror as mentioned in the post above. Also updated the question so now the format given to datetime.strp is %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S. Also if we use %p then we have to use %I:%M:%S but even then I still get the valuerror